# Why my transposeMatrix function doesn't work?

Tags: function

Why this code dosen't work? How can I improve it?  I think function should be void type.
The function transposeMatrix() that takes as an argument a 4 × 5 matrix and a 5 × 4 matrix. 
The function transpose the 4 × 5 matrix and store the results in the 5 × 4 matrix.

```
void transposeMatrix(int a, int b, int N[a][b], int M[b][a])  // get 2 arrays
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {     // go through arrays
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            M[i][c] = N[i][c];
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int a = 4, b = 5;

    int M[b][a] =  // fist array 
    {
        { 0, 10, 22, 30 },
        { 4, 50, 6, 77 },
        { 80, 9, 1000, 111 },
        { 12, 130, 14, 15 },
        { 16, 17, 102, 103 }

    };

    int N[a][b] =    // second array
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  }
    };

    printf("array  M\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < b; i++)
            printf("%4i", M[i][c]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    transposeMatrix(a, b, N, M);  // call function

    printf("array  M after transposeMatrix function/n ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < b; i++)

            printf("%4i", M[i][c]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime we take transpose we use atranspose[i][j]=a[j][i].

Whereas in ur code u are using M[i][c] = N[i][c]
which is wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int matrix[5][5],transpose_matrix[5][5];
    int i,j,rows,cols;
    // Taking Input In Array

    cout<<"Enter Number of ROWS :";
    cin>>rows;

    cout<<"Enter Number Of COLS  :";
    cin>>cols;
    for( i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for( j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout<<"\n Matrix You Entered\n";

    for( i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for( j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"     ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    // Calculating Transpose of Matrix
    cout<<"\n\n\nTranspose of Entered Matrix\n";
    for( i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for( j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            transpose_matrix[j][i]=matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    //Displaying Final Resultant Array
    for( i=0;i<cols;i++) {
        for( j=0;j<rows;j++)
        {
            cout<<transpose_matrix[i][j]<<"    ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```